# is there any possible reason why this code doesnt work?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
{% for user in usersList %}
  <tr>
        <td>{{ user.get_Product_ID() }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.get_Name() }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.get_Price() }}</td>
        {% if {{ user.get_Quantity() }} == 0 }
        <td>OUT OF STOCK</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{ user.get_Quantity() }}</td>
        {% endif %}
```

it gives me error messages like these

```
    args = [self.parse_math2()]
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 517, in 
parse_math2
    left = self.parse_pow()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 528, in 
parse_pow
    left = self.parse_unary()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 546, in 
parse_unary
    node = self.parse_primary()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 581, in 
parse_primary
    node = self.parse_dict()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 662, in 
parse_dict
    self.stream.expect('colon')
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py", line 384, in 
expect
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Comment: You didn't give much code so it's really hard to tell where those error messages are coming from. Is there any way to include more relevant pieces of your code? It seems like you have a syntax error (probably a typo) somewhere else.

Comment: no... thats the only code ive added that resulted in this to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add more {{}} into {}.

and you missed a % in "if" line and "endfor" too.

You should change your code to this

```
{% for user in usersList %}
  <tr>
        <td>{{ user.get_Product_ID() }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.get_Name() }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.get_Price() }}</td>
        {% if user.get_Quantity() == 0 %}
        <td>OUT OF STOCK</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{ user.get_Quantity() }}</td>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi ,ive done like you said but it still have the same error message https://prnt.sc/qmjwoe

Comment: i changed the answer and i check it in here https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/